# Lambda Expressions: How to analyze how a delegate is stored as an Expression?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

This code:

```
var lambda = Products.Where( p => p.name == "chair");
```

can be written like this code:

```
var propertyName = "name";
var value = "chair";
var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
var property = typeof(Product).GetProperty(propertyName);
var comparison = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(arg, property),
    Expression.Constant(value));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(comparison, arg).Compile();
```

If I have any Lambda expression like this:

```
Products.Where( p => p.name.Contains("chair") );
```

How could I determine how to write the Expression like above?  Is there a way to "debug" the expression tree so that I can program it manually?

EDIT:

I saw promising answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289134/how-to-create-an-expression-tree-to-do-something-similar-to-the-sql-like-comma) but it didn't end up with working code.  Here's their version (the error is the StartsWith method is given a non-string value):

```
ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", 
    new[] { typeof(string) });
var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(p, method, 
    Expression.Constant("root"), p);
```

Comment: Maybe something like this?? http://xte.codeplex.com/

Comment: @mellamokb: bool (string x) => x.Contains("chair") produced an exception error in that software.  Very good suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let the compiler do the work.

If you instead of

```
func<string,bool> MyLambda = p => p.name.Contains("chair");
```

write

```
Expression<func<string,bool>> MyExpression = p => p.name.Contains("chair");
```

Then you get a nice "MyExpression" that you can inspect in a debugger.